# How can I revert data filtered by ion-searchbar in ionic 4 with angular?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm trying to use ionic 4 ion-searchbar ui component with angular. I can filter the data use following component, but I can't revert the filter to original data
my component looks this:

```
...
export class RepertorioPage implements OnInit {

  data: any;
  filtredData: any;

  constructor(private newsService: NewsService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.newsService.getData('everything?q=bitcoin&from=2018-12-25&sortBy=publishedAt')
        .subscribe(data => {
        this.data = data
        this.filtredData = data
        })

  }

   ...

  getFiltredRepertorio(ev: any){

    let serVal = ev.target.value;
    if(serVal && serVal.trim() != ''){
      this.filtredData.articles = this.data.articles.filter((a) => {
        return (a.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(serVal.toLowerCase()) > -1);
      })
    }
  }

}
```

and my html like this:

```
...
<ion-content>
    <!-- List of Text Items -->
    <ion-searchbar showCancelButton cancelButtonText="Custom Cancel" (ionChange) = getFiltredRepertorio($event) id="searchText"></ion-searchbar>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item (click)="getRepertorio(article)" *ngFor="let article of filtredData?.articles">
        <ion-label>{{article.title}}</ion-label>
      </ion-item>

    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

What is going wrong? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to clone data instead of pointing its reference. 
for example with lodash (import * as _ from 'lodash') with clone or cloneDeep

```
this.data = _.clone(data)
this.filtredData = data
```

Comment: Hi, Almost there. Now I can revert but not to original data when I have no text in ion-searchbar

Comment: maybe because of serVal.trim() != ''"

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

If the formcontrol is causing trouble, we can do the same with `ionChange`:

```html
<ion-searchbar ... (ionChange)="doFilter($event)"></ion-searchbar>
```

and `doFilter` would look like this:

```ts
doFilter(val) {
  this.filteredData =  this.data.map(data => data.articles).map(options =>
    options.filter(option => 
       option.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.value.toLowerCase()) > -1)
    )
}
```

**[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-yrjf9p?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**

---

ORIGINAL:

I would keep the data as an Observable and use the async pipe and a formcontrol:

```ts
myControl = new FormControl();
filteredData: Observable<any[]>;
data: Observable<any[]>;

// ...

ngOnInit() {
  this.data = this.newsService.getData('...')

  this.filteredData = this.myControl.valueChanges
    .switchMap(value => this.filter(value))
}

filter(value: string): Observable<any[]> {
  return this.data.map(data => data.articles)
    .map(options => options
      .filter(option => option.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) > -1)
  )
}
```

Then the template where you set the async pipe and mark the formcontrol, to which changes we listen to and filter:

```html
<ion-content>
  <ion-searchbar ... [formControl]="myControl"></ion-searchbar>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item ... *ngFor="let article of filteredData | async">
      <ion-label>{{article.title}}</ion-label>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Here's **[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-3mxv7h?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**

*As a note, don't use `any`, type your data :)*

Comment: Hi, I try this code but I got a error saying the formControl is not a property in ion-searchbar

Comment: Updated answer, try with `ionChange` instead :)